# How to select true value when combining alphanumeric?

Tags: php, mysql

mysql: `customer_number = int` (cannot be changed)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE customer_number= '123F'"
```

The RESULT should be empty.

The query has a result which is incorrect because, MySQL ignore any alphabet character which form part of the value with an integer datatype, eg.'F'

Comment: Show the result to help us understand your problem, which is hard right now

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the value provided is strictly integer.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE customer_number= '123F' 
AND '123F' REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'";
```

`AND` needs both conditions compulsorily.

So, even if MySQL ignores `F` from `123F` and treats it as `123`, second condition will return `FALSE` and `123F` will fail regular expression of strictly integer condition.

This will have following results:

`123` -> pass

`123F` -> fail

Comment: You should be checking that the comparison value is numeric, not the field in the table (since that is defined as `INT`): `'123F' REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tested it and worked 100%

Comment: @Nick, thanks for guiding me. I have corrected my answer and it worked for the op.

Comment: @Pupil no worries. Glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `customer_number` to string:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE CAST(customer_number as CHAR(50)) = '123F'
```

The above query is of course not SARGable. Consider processing the comparison argument on the client side before the construction of the query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/292681/5)

Answer (score 0):

Or check as first condition if the integer from the string equal the string (change the string to your fieldname) :

```
SELECT * FROM clients 
WHERE
  '123F'+0 = '123F' 
AND
  customer_number= '123F';
```